# regex not returning results of a search (problem with white space)

Tags: angular, regex, typescript, search, filtering

I am currently working on integrating a search feature using Angular. The feature will enable users to search for products based on their respective **(brandName)**. As part of this integration, I am implementing a function in my component that retrieves all available brands on the website and displays them in a dropdown list for the user to select from.
Here is the code of the component :

```js
loadBrands() {
  if (this.brands?.length) {
    return
  }

  const operator = this.storage.getItem<OperatorStorage>(StorageKeys.operator)
  const lang_key = this.langService.getCurrentLang()

  this.cardService.getAvailableBrands(operator?.operator).subscribe(
    (brandsResponse: any) => {
      const parseJson = (jsonString: string) => {
        try {
          return JSON.parse(jsonString)
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error parsing JSON:', error)
          return {} // Return an empty object in case of parsing failure
        }
      }

      this.brands = brandsResponse
        .map((brand: any) => {
          //console.log(brand)
          // Parse the brandName and storeName JSON strings into objects
          const brandNameObject = parseJson(brand.brandName)
          const storeNameObject = parseJson(brand.storeName)
          //console.log(brandNameObject)
          //console.log(storeNameObject)

          // Get the brandName and storeName based on the lang_key
          const brandName = brandNameObject[lang_key] || brandNameObject['en']
          const storeName = storeNameObject[lang_key] || storeNameObject['en']
          console.log(brandName)
          //console.log(storeName)

          return {
            ...brand,
            name: `${brandName} - ${storeName || ''}`,
            id: brand.brandID
          }
        })
        .sort((brand1, brand2) => {
          //return brand1.name.localeCompare(brand2.name);
          return brand1.name
            .toLowerCase()
            .trim()
            .localeCompare(brand2.name.toLowerCase().trim())
        })
      console.log(this.brands)
    },
    (error) => {
      console.error('Error loading brands:', error)
    }
  )
}
```

And here is the HTML code for the dropdown list :

```html
<div
  class="social"
  *ngIf="isShowDropdown"
  [@fadeInOnEnter]
  [@fadeOutOnLeave]
  clickOutSide
  (OnClickOut)="isShowDropdown = false"
  avoidClass="search-input-control"
>
  <div class="option-container">
    <ul>
      <li (click)="clearFilter()" [ngClass]="{'selected': !selectedBrand}">
        <span>{{"BRAND_EMPTY_OPTION" | translate}}</span>
      </li>
      <li
        [ngClass]="{'selected': selectedBrand==brand.id}"
        *ngFor="let brand of brands | searchFilter: searchForm.value"
        (click)="filterCardById(brand.id, brand.name)"
      >
        <span>{{brand.name}}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I'm applying a custom filter pipe to refine the search results. The filter pipe uses regex to search for the relevant data in the JSON response received from the server. The search is performed on a property called brandDesc.
Here is the code for the filter pipe :

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core'
@Pipe({
  name: 'searchFilter'
})
export class SearchFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(brands: any, search: string): any {
    if (brands) {
      const regexp = new RegExp(search, 'i')
      const properties = Object.keys(brands[0])
      return [
        ...brands.filter((item) => {
          return properties.some((property) => regexp.test(item[property]))
        })
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The issue lies in the values of the keys found in the brandDesc property. For instance, if the user enters `amazon` in the search bar, the results will not appear in the dropdown list until they add a space after their query, like so: `amazon` . This is because the JSON response from the server looks like this:

```js
"brandDesc": "{\"en\":\"Amazon UAE Store Card\",\"fr\":\"Amazon UAE Store Card\",\"ar\":\"امازون\",\"pl\":\"Karta sklepu Amazon ZEA\"}"
```

Similarly, when the user types `itunes`, all the results show up in the dropdown list, but if they add a space after their query like this: `itunes` , some of the results disappear from the dropdown list because the JSON response may look like this:

```js
"brandDesc": "{\"en\":\"iTunes Cards for UAE Store\",\"fr\":\"iTunes Cards for UAE Store\",\"ar\":\"بطاقة ايتيونز للشراء من متجر تطبيقات أبل الإماراتي\",\"pl\":\"Karta iTunes do kupienia w ZEA Apple App Store\"}"
```

or like this:

```js
"brandDesc": "{\"en\":\"iTunes\",\"fr\":\"iTunes\",\"ar\":\"ايتيونز\",\"pl\":\"iTunes\"}"
```

So the question is : Is it possible to handle this from the frontend or the backend? And if it can be handled from the frontend, what changes should I make in the code?

P.S : the JSON response structure is like this :
{
"brandID": "53",
"brandName": "{"en":"Amazon","fr":"Amazon","ar":"امازون","pl":"Amazon"}",
"brandDesc": "{"en":"Amazon UAE Store Card","fr":"Amazon UAE Store Card","ar":"امازون","pl":"Karta sklepu Amazon ZEA"}",
"storeName": "{"en":"UAE Store","fr":"UAE Store","ar":"المتجر الاماراتي","pl":"UAE Sklep"}",
"brandNameAr": null,
"brandDescAr": null,
"storeNameAr": null,
"brandStatus": "1",
"imgPath": "https://karti-cards-images.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/amazon.webp",
"id": 0
}

Comment: Note you need to double backslashes in regular template literals. ``${search}\s*`` must ``${search}\\s*``

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Could you please take a moment to review the code again because I edited the filter pipe code? I apologize for any inconvenience this may cause.

Comment: `new RegExp(search, 'i')` is not safe, you need to escape the `search` before using in the `RegExp`.

Comment: Is there a reason for not [trimming](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) the search term before searching for it? If I understand correctly, that would solve the problem.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I updated the code to this :                                                                                    const escapedSearch = search.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
const regexp = new RegExp(`\\b${escapedSearch}\\s*`, 'i');                                                              but still not showing the results until the user manually add a space

Comment: @tao if you trimmed the search term then no results will be returned at all, I tried it before

Comment: I can only help with regex, since the code you posted cannot be run. There is only one more thing regarding regex: do not use `\b` since the first char of the `search` can be a non-word char. In this case, replace ``\\b`` with ``(?!\\B\\w)``

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for your assistance. I will attempt to handle this on my own and await further replies.